# How better to restore modified files after git stash?

Tags: git, git-stash

Making git pull I got errors  :

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        public/js/file.js
        public/file.json
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
```

I saved list of all modified files with

```
git status
```

and command run

```
git stash
```

I merged all files now I need to restore all my changes. List of all files is rather big, including
deleting/new files, like:

```
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    app/Http/Controllers/ItemController.php
        new file:   app/Http/Controllers/BoxController.php
        
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   .gitignore
        modified:   app/Http/Controllers/ItemController.php
        
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        app/Http/Controllers/ItemController.php
        app/Http/Requests/ItemRequest.php
```

When I need to restore some modified files I can apply changes manually, but

1. How to restore deleted/new files?
2. Is the listing of all modified files is rather big, how can I make it better, not manually checking them one by one?

Comment: You want to re-apply what you've stashed earlier? Did you try the typical `git stash apply`? (on your clean post-merge working tree)

Comment: Is the second `git status` the output after you did `git pull` or `git merge`? If so, the merge was not complete and you need to finish it before trying to restore your stash.

Comment: If on the other hand, the `git status` is after you did `git stash apply`, you are pretty much SOL. This is a good reason why we recommend committing often. The more often you commit, then you are much less likely to encounter a situation where you need to resolve conflicts in a massive number of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restore your changes do `git stash apply`. However, it looks like your merge is incomplete. You need to `git commit` the merge before trying to apply your stash.